# MySQL database record exists, but does not return

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a screenshot of database records ( don't mind weird entries, they are for testing)
http://i42.tinypic.com/9uumpc.png

But when I run following query no matter what, upper/lower/quotes/double quotes it returns empty.

```
SELECT * FROM BusDetails WHERE category='$cat'
```

$cat = "Accountants"

it doesn't return anything. Even though there is a record with such category. 
And I know its not my PHP fault, I tried running this query in myadmin SQL.

Comment: If it works in phpmyadmin that would indicate it IS your PHP at fault.

Comment: Can you paste your whole PHP code you're trying to use?  There's probably something wrong in it.

Comment: So wait, you ran the query in PHPMyAdmin and it returned 0 still? -- Try running SELECT * FROM [backtick]BusDetails[backtick] WHERE [backtick]category[backtick] = 'Accountants';  IF this shows up correctly, use back ticks around your tables/columns.

Comment: Nope, even with backtick it returns zero. I double checked spellings and even copy/pasted names still zero. The category field is varchar(255)

Comment: Are you sure there's no padding in that string or in the database? Also, you better be doing [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you could have a whole host of other problems.

Comment: Found error and fixed, as suggested by one person: I have an space in categories, turns out that line break in PHP file caused it to add spaces to entries. – arleitiss 10 hours ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of learning best practices here is an example of using a PDO (PHP Data Object) to interact with your database.

```
//Make a connection to your database.
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=<YOURDB>', '<USERNAME>', '<PASSWORD>');

$cat = "Accountants";
$STH = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM BusDetails WHERE category = :cat");
$STH->bindParam(":cat", $cat); //This binds your parameter and replaces :cat 
                               //with the value of $cat escaped

$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$STH->execute();

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    //interact with results here
}
```

This will allow you to execute the query you have provided along with escape any characters that can lead to injections (See Bobby Tables). Should $cat ever be assigned to a value given by the user (i.e. search term) this code would work as is.

If your query ever grows to require additional parameters (which I assume they will) you can simply add additional :param place holders in the query and bind the value with the bindParam method as shown.